# Securing Restful Web Services with OAuth2 with JWT

Tags: web-services, api, oauth-2.0, cxf, jwt

Hi i am new to Apache cxf rest API security side.I want to rest API which have good security with authorization.I found Apache cxf gives Ouath2 security features(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html).So And i need to use json web token(http://jwt.io/) to send to API for authorization.Simply i need to use secured line for send request to rest API.So far i have simple design.[image]

And my REST api have CRUD Operations to database.I thought send JWT as Access token in request header.And API side verify the user and send data back to user.I have two questions.First one is Is this the best design for this kind of application.And second one is if this is best way how to generate Tokens and is that we need to keep those tokens in server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a good design

I can explain it with github web api's

```
Authorize
```

First u validate urself for using API by sending client id and callback url in request (here u specify access level ie.scope) and u receive a code

```
Access_token
```

Then u exchange this code for access token (this time with client secret included in req parameter)

This access token received is used for all future calls made by u on behalf of user

Nd ya u store this token and refresh token at server

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow

Although this is specific to github , similar flow follows for twitter , linked in and slightly different for facebook web api's

Comment: just in case u r on node js there's a great framework passport.js

`http://passportjs.org/`